# Windows Vista - Cannot connect to Wireless Network

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-router

I am using a Windows Vista laptop. I cannot connect to the internet on it, no matter how hard I try. On ***'Connect to a Network'***, the only option is ***'Broadband Connection  PPPoE Connection'***. On ***'Set up a Connection or Network'***, two options are missing that would be VERY helpful, 'Manually Connect to a Wireless Network' and ***'Set up a Wireless a hoc (Computer-to-Computer) Network'***.
What do I do?

Comment: Did it ever work? It seems as it's not detecting your wireless adapter. It would be useful if you list the laptop maker and model, as well as if you could check if your wifi adapter is listed under your hardware devices.

Comment: Yes, it did. But we got a new router recently.